# Написание плагина на JQuery

Tags: jquery, плагин

Всем привет.

Захотелось при работе с паралаксом написать такой плагин, который бы менял плавно цвет бэкграунда или цвет текста в зависимости от скроллинга.

Начав писать плагин понял что удобно было бы передавать в параметрах функцию, которая бы вычисляла значение элементов на странице. Но вот не получается реализовать это. Параметры выглядят так:

```
$("#header").colorchanger({
    startColor:"#FFFFFF",
    endColor:"#333333",
    cssProperty:"background",
    startTop : function(){
        return parseInt($("#c-main").css("height")) - 
               parseInt($("#c-main").css("height")) / 5;
    },

    endTop:parseInt($("#c-main").css("height"))

});
```

Как обратиться к функции так чтобы она заработала, пока она приходит в виде текста?

Comment: вам надо при инициализации вычислять или потом тоже ? colorchanger это ваш плагин ? наверное хорошо бы его исходник увидеть. если это callback из плагина, то надо делать typeof(param)==='function'

Comment: @eicto Потом тоже т.к. если изменят размер окна, то и положение начала и конца тоже меняется, если задается относительно элементов. Да, это мой плагин. Понадобилось написать для одного проект, а потом идея понравилась решил развить её в плагин.
Исходник тут можно увидеть: http://termolaev.ru/jquery.colorchanger.js